# What is the internal method System.Double.IsNegative() for in C#?

Tags: c#, double, standard-library

While browsing the source for `System.Double`, I came across this method:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
internal static unsafe bool IsNegative(double d)
{
  return (*(long*) &d & long.MinValue) == long.MinValue;
}
```

It doesn't seem to be used anywhere in the `System.Double` struct. Is it used somewhere else?

As I don't have the full source of the C# standard library on my machine, I can't simply browse references to it via Visual Studio. I also found [this API documentation for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.isnegative?view=netstandard-2.1), but it doesn't describe why one might want to use it.

Comment: It is used [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,219).

Comment: @Sweeper Ah interesting, do you happen to know why it's used as opposed to something like `> 0`?

Comment: For one, `-0.0 < 0.0` is false, but `IsNegative(-0.0)` is true.